# How do I DD backup the Microsoft Surface onto a Image file? Has anyone done this and restored it successfully?

Tags: 14.04, backup, dd, surface

I normally back up my PCs with a disk dump. Its effective but slow, but required for us. I usually do something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=512k of=/mnt/MyUsbStick4TB/BackupOfMyCDrive_sda.dd
```

Can anyone confirm if this method works for the **Microsoft Surface**? For example making a USB Stick with a live Ubuntu Image, booting the surface pro with stick, and DD'ing the internal 64GB drive from the surface onto the stick, and... **then RESTORING it safely**?

Has anyone done this before? If I can do this, then I will try to buy a expensive USB Penstick, and always carry it with my surface as a full DD Backup of the Surface when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

What is your actual problem? Are you already booting successfully from USB or are you asking if this is possible?

If you can boot from the USB into Ubuntu on the device, why shouldn't `dd` work as usual?

I'd rather recommend using Microsoft tools like `dism` for individual partitions where possible and backing up the partition table separately (if there is such a thing, you may probably find `mmcblk0` instead of `sda`), `dism` usually achieves better compression ratio than `dd`+`lzma2`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I havent booted with a USB memory stick at the moment, but was curious if any users on the forums have successfully backed up a "Microsoft Surface" tablet with DD. (Thanks for the tip about dism, but I never figured out how to do dd+lzma2, so I always just only used dd, because on uncompressing your dd.bz2, you will run out of memory: Backup via [dd if=/dev/sda bs=512k of=/backup.dd ; bzip2 /backupdd], but restoring this method always fails due to running out of memory when piping: [bunzip2 /backup.dd.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sda]

Comment: Thanks for the Dism tip. I studied it and it works great for win7/8 fine (I studied it from: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825072.aspx), but I cant use DISM for the current situation. Has anyone tried to DD backup the Microsoft Surface, and then restore it?

Comment: Since the surface only boots UEFI drives, how do I make a Live Bootable USB Pen drive with UEFI support that allows my surface to work on it?